# How to include the system.data.sqlite.core.1.0.108 NUGet package in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, nuget, using

I would like to be using sqlite such as I do for sqlserver, in my uses clauses:

using System.Data.Sqlite etc...
What steps should I do?

That did not solve the problem, because I do not have any reference del tipo system.data.sqlite to add. Therefore I cannot use the sqlite framework at all. All i have is the nuget package but I do not know how to install it in VS.

Comment: Did you search google? Also see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes I did, but I could not find help. Maybe I am too dumb to install this. Please offere anu help...thanks. Other have sugested to download the source code of sqllite this I also done, but then what comes next? I do not understand what is it so complicated...but maybe I am just dumb..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.data.sqlite tutorial for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470583/system-data-sqlite-tutorial-for-c-sharp)

Comment: My nuget package i obtained from here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite

but now I do I install it in VS?

Comment: In the page that you provided there is an instruction: in Package Manager execute the code: `Install-Package System.Data.SQLite -Version 1.0.108`

Comment: I was able to open the package manager console in VS and type the command and now it is installed. that worked

Comment: I have a last question. I think it i still in range of the answer. Now that I have added sqlite, I cannot find the class SQLiteConnection, ob whole  I have added:
using System.Data.SQLite;
What do I do still to do more to establish connection to my sqlite database.? Then I would like to assign the answer to the question to karbovnichy

Comment: Found the answer myself, just adding: using System.Data.SQLite.Generic;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem was to implement the usage of Sqlite in VisualStudio in one of my projects. 
1)I started downloading: the system.data.sqlite.core.1.0.108 NUGet package, from here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite
2)But I did not know how to install it. Then someone pointed out that there is the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio and I can install by Console.
3)Following the tutorial on the same page I did this.
Notice: you must have a solution opened in the VS in order for the PM to install the package. Packages will be installed on that Application only.
4)After that you can access all the functionalities of SQLite by including it with:
Using System.Data.SQLite and System.Data.Sqlite.Generic